# Unable to access Twitter API in Jupyter Notebook. How do I solve authentication problem?

Tags: python, twitter, jupyter-notebook, twitter-oauth

I have installed the twitter and python-twitter modules.

```
import tweepy as tp
import twitter

twitter_keys = {
            'consumer_key':        '*',
            'consumer_secret':     '*',
            'access_token_key':    '*',
            'access_token_secret': '*'
        }
auth=tp.OAuthHandler(twitter_keys['consumer_key'],twitter_keys['consumer_secret'])
auth.set_access_token(twitter_keys['access_token_key'],twitter_keys['access_token_key'])
api=tp.API(auth)
INDIA_WOE_ID = 23424848
results = api.trends_place(_id = 1)
```

And this is all it can show me.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TweepError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-51682b25a788> in <module>
----> 1 results = api.trends_place(_id = 1)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py in _call(*args, **kwargs)
    248                 return method
    249             else:
--> 250                 return method.execute()
    251         finally:
    252             method.session.close()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py in execute(self)
    231                     raise RateLimitError(error_msg, resp)
    232                 else:
--> 233                     raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
    234 
    235             # Parse the response payload

TweepError: [{'code': 32, 'message': 'Could not authenticate you.'}]
```

I have set up the Dev environment. I have tried regenerating my key. I have scoured through numerous websites looking for an answer, all to no avail.

Please do provide steps on how to solve said issue.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this work from you from a command line?

Comment: I have successfully tested tweepy in Jupyter notebooks with a valid consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_key, and access_key_secret. Given that the error you received is an authentication error, I believe there is a problem with your credentials rather than the tool or method.

Comment: @DavidScott I do get the same error from command line. Also, I did think the same regarding my credentials. I have regenerated both the consumer keys and access keys and updated them respectively in the code. Is maybe something wrong with the app I created? Fml I just realised my question says 'Jupiter'.

Comment: While there may be something further wrong with the app, I did get a page not found error when I ran the last line of your query, I... Oh. I see the problem.

Comment: @DavidScott Update: If I don't run the auth.set_access_token method, I do not the error anymore. Any idea why that particular method is causing the issue?

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed it. You provided the set_access_token method with the access token twice instead of the access token and the access token secret. Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the Tweepy documentation, the set_access_token() command requires the access key, and the access key secret.

Change this line:

auth.set_access_token(twitter_keys['access_token_key'],twitter_keys['access_token_key'])

To this:

auth.set_access_token(twitter_keys['access_token_key'],twitter_keys['access_token_secret'])

This should resolve your authentication error by providing the full authentication requirements.

Comment: FML. Thanks a lot. Will remind myself not to be lazy and copy names.

Comment: Happy to help, it's so easy to overlook that stuff. Was looking at this multiple times while testing and trying to reproduce but didn't catch it till just a bit ago.